# Can we set the default tab we see when we log in?

Tags: feature-request, support

I prefer to use the 'Newest Questions' view in the SE sites I frequent. Is there a way to when you log in or click the site logo to go to this tab rather thn the 'Active' tab? If not, would it be possible to add this feature?

Comment: It should already be like this. Has been for months now.

Comment: I use the newest questions view too, but I'm just in the habit of clicking the "Questions" button instead of the logo when I want to go back to the list; you might want to try that

Comment: So do I, actually. I don't like clicking it againg when I navigate to the site from elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with just clicking the questions icon. This will take you to your saved tab.

When you click on the link for the exchange, it takes you to that exchange's front page. The front page shows you a custom set of questions with its own tabs that are not the same set as the `/questions` tabs (such as hot). For every exchange aside from Stack Overflow (which shows "interesting" as the selected tab) the custom tab selected is "active" when visiting the exchange's front page.

This is by design.