# Should the Top Questions really default to active?

Tags: discussion

On the homepage of a site ([movies.stackexchange.com](http://movies.stackexchange.com) for example) the Top Questions defaults to **Active**.

- **Active** is anything that has been Asked, Answered, Commented, or Modified recently.
- **Hot** are questions with the most views, answers, and votes within the last few days.

To me, as a user, I would have more interest in the **Hot** tab rather than the **Active** tab because the **Hot** tab is what everyone else is looking at.  Should the home page really default to **Active**?  IMHO I don't think so.

Comment: Are you saying this is for everyone, not just you? I find I get 'Newest' when I come to a questions page, if I have selected it at least once - I must have done this early on. I think that is saved as a page preference from that point per user. I have just confirmed - choose a differnt sort, quit and re-enter, the page presents that sort.

Comment: Related, maybe dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73570/can-we-set-the-default-tab-we-see-when-we-log-in

Comment: Maybe for anonymous users this would make sense, but it would greatly reduce the number of people looking at edited questions and new answers. In fact if we're all looking at the hot tab, who's looking at new content to determine how "hot" it is?

Answer (score 0):

I added this as answer from my comment above.

Are you saying this is for everyone, not just you? I find I get 'Newest' when I come to a questions page, if I have selected it at least once - I must have done this early on. I think that is saved as a page preference from that point per user.

UPDATE: I have just confirmed on Movies.SE - choose a different sort, quit and re-enter, the page presents that sort. Change back to 'Newest', quit and re-enter, it presents in 'Newest' order.

Comment: UPDATE2: I now understand - I must have made a choice of sort for my pages early on and SAVED it that way as a Favorite. This is why it presents consistently for me. If I use the toolbar to get back to meta or main, I then see that it defaults to the 'Active' sort.